# RTree is not adding the geometric line in the entries

Tags: java, indexing, r-tree

I am using davidmoten RTree to index the edges from the graph. however, rtree is not adding the edges in the entry.
RTreeIndexer.class

```
public static RTree<Integer, Line> createRTree(CoreGraph graph) {
        RTree<Integer, Line> rtree = RTree.create();

        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> adjMap = graph.getAdjancencyMap();

        for (Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> entry : adjMap.entrySet()) {
            int startNodeId = entry.getKey();
            double startLong = graph.getNodeFromMap(startNodeId).getLongitude();
            double startLatit = graph.getNodeFromMap(startNodeId).getLatitude();
            Map<Integer, Double> adjList = entry.getValue();

            for (Entry<Integer, Double> adjacentNodes : adjList.entrySet()) {
                int endNodeId = adjacentNodes.getKey();
                double endLong = graph.getNodeFromMap(endNodeId).getLongitude();
                double endLatit = graph.getNodeFromMap(endNodeId).getLatitude();
                Line line = Geometries.line(startLong, startLatit, endLong, endLatit);
                int edgeId = graph.getEdgeId(startNodeId, endNodeId);
                if (rtree.isEmpty()) {
                    rtree.add(edgeId, line);
                }

            }
        }
        return rtree;

    }
```

Comment: I don't know the library you're using but doesn't the line `if (rtree.isEmpty()) {` prevent your graph from being added? It ensures that only the first edge will be added to the R-tree data structure.

Comment: Did you try debugging this code? What were your findings?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I have left that if part just to see if it adds any edge in the entries. It doesn't add any even all the inputs are taken by the function itself. The tree is still empty. I am not understanding the issue here.

Comment: @kiner_shah, yes I debugged the code. The first edge will be passed when there is no tree. However, when returning it still passes null value for the tree entry! This is really confusing to me! I am trying to use this framework for the very first time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I am using Davidmoten Rtree indexing framework Here's the link: https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree